# Transform the data from one form to another using ES6

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, es6-modules

I have the data as follows:

```
[
  {
    name: "ABC",
    points: [
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/26",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/27",
        value: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "DEF",
    points: [
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/26",
        value: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/27",
        value: 3
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to transform the above data into:

```
[
  {
    timestamp: "2017/09/26",
    "ABC": 1,
    "DEF": 0
  },
  {
    timestamp: "2017/09/27",
    "ABC": 2,
    "DEF": 3
  }
]
```

I've just started learning ES6 and underscore. Trying to apply underscore to transform, but not able to succeed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not any sign of effort. OP has just shared input and output formats. This makes it a requirement and not a problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let arr = [
  {
    name: "ABC",
    points: [
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/26",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/27",
        value: 2
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "DEF",
    points: [
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/26",
        value: 0
      },
      {
        timestamp: "2017/09/27",
        value: 3
      },
    ]
  }
]

let result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    for(let element of b.points){
        a[element.timestamp] = a[element.timestamp] || {};
        let newObj = {};
        newObj[b.name] = element.value;
        Object.assign(a[element.timestamp], newObj);
    }
    return a;
}, {});


result = Object.keys(result).map(key => Object.assign(result[key], {timestamp : key}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just a pointer, for such answers, try to use minified data. That way, emphasis would remain on your logic. Also try to explain your approach, what and why you did this. This will help readers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared effort, I'll focus this answer on algorithm and leave the implementation part to you.

#### Algorithm:

- Create a hashmap that will store the groups.
- A group will have a signature `{ name: valueAsPerDate}`
- Now loop over data. For every object,

  - Search for current date in hashmap. If exists, add group with necessary vallue.
  - If not, add it to the hashmap and then add group values to it.
  - Once above loop is over, again loop over the hashmap and return objects in your format, where timestamp will be your group name and you already have values in that object.

Ta-da!!!

Comment: **Note:** I have purposely not added code in above answer. I have also added a caveat for it. If there is anything apart from that that is *incorrect/ not-required* please comment it along with your vote.